# Logical operation on the contents of a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, data-manipulation, tensor

I have a list named 'datastate' of shape (?,10) which is getting filled with the results of 10 batch samples in tensorflow (all tensors).  In other words, with a batch size of 256, this will be populated with 10 different tensors of size 256.

in pseudocode below ....

```
datastate = {}

for sample in range(num_samples):
    datastate[sample] = batch_results
```

What I would like to do next is define a variable like 'datastate_change', which would determine if the i-th record of batch_results was changed versus the (i-1)th record of batch_results. This might look something like the following if Pandas style syntax worked ... but I'm not clear on how to do this inside of tf during the sess.run.

```
for sample in range(num_samples):
    datastate[sample] = batch_results
    datastate_change[sample] = batch_results - batch_results.shift(1)
```

To be a bit more concrete, if a single instance of batch_results are [1,1,1,0,1] I would like to have datastate[1] = [1,1,1,0,1] and datastate_change[1] = [1,0,0,-1,1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a satisfactory answer on my own - key was numpy is better analogue plugin than pandas....
First I create a copy of my datastate which is padded along the top with zeros
Then I slice off the bottom row of this copy
Lastly I subtract the two.

```
top_paddings = tf.constant([[1, 0]]) #New tensor with the 'top' being zeros
top_padded_datastate_[sample] = tf.pad(datastate[sample], top_paddings, "CONSTANT")
top_padded_datastate[sample] = top_padded_datastate_[sample][:-1]
datastate_changes[sample] = tf.subtract(datastate[sample], top_padded_datastate[sample])
```